# Disable selectbox options using Angularstrap

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular strap select box. But, I want to disable all the options of the selectbox, how do I achieve this?

```
$scope.itemsPerPageList = ['All','10','20','30','40'];

<select class="span2" 
     ng-init="itemsPerPage = itemsPerPageList[0]" 
     ng-model="itemsPerPage" ng-change="changePager()" 
     ng-options="obj as obj for obj in itemsPerPageList" 
     data-style="btn-primary" bs-select>
</select>
```

I tried using `ng-disabled=true`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using AngularStrap v1.x, which is outdated and not supported anymore. In AngularStrap v2.x, select is done this way:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
    ng-model="selectedIcon"
    data-html="1"
    ng-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons"
    bs-select>
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

And `ng-disabled=true` works with it. Take a look [at the doc](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects#selects).